# Cannot see "Add code generation item" option

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, database-project

**Situation:**

I've got a project in Visual Studio. I added an edmx EF 4.2 model using a Database Project as the source. I now want to create the DbContext generator.

**Problem:**

However, when I right-click the design surface of the .edmx model, I do not see an "Add code generation item" option. What am I missing?

**Background:**

Here's the tutorial I'm using: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx

I'm using the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview, and Entity Framework 4.2 (via NuGet).

Comment: What version of .Net framework is your project targeting? Also did you installed templates?

Comment: I'm targeting .NET 4.5, and I installed EF 4.2, which I believe installed templates as well. I haven't installed any additional templates. My problem is that I don't even have the option to "Add code generation item" to select a template.